# Copy of incoming message is blank

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to copy a message with an attachment and forward it to the specified address.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.Account
      
    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    'Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    Set objectNS = outlookApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
    Set inboxItems = objectNS.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
     
Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim MessageInfo
    Dim Result
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        MsgBox ("debug msg")
        
        Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
        Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        
        Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
        Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("mail@mail.com")
        myItem.Subject = Item.Subject
        myItem.SendUsingAccount = oNS.Accounts.Item(2)
        myItem.HTMLBody = Item.Body
        myItem.Display
        'myItem.Send
        
    End If
ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub
```

The script is launched at startup.
The event is triggered when an item appears in the inbox.
Since I have several accounts tied to Outlook, I use:

```
Set objectNS = outlookApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
```

The message body is not copied (for example, text + picture).

I tried:

```
myItem.HTMLBody = Item.RTFbody
```

or

```
myItem.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLbody
```

But the message remains blank.

Comment: Could you check what `Item.HTMLbody` is returning. Is it Blank string?

Comment: I am not a programmer, by coincidence I had to tackle this task.
If i do  `myItem.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLbody`  message field remains empty.I will try to do `MsgBox (Item.HTMLbody) ` see what happens. I can do it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Work with [MailItem.Forward method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.Forward(method))*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Debug.Print Item.Subject
        FwItem Item
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub FwItem(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim MsgFwd As Outlook.MailItem
    Set MsgFwd = Item.Forward
        MsgFwd.Subject = Item.Subject
        MsgFwd.Recipients.Add "0m3r@Email.com"
        MsgFwd.Save
        MsgFwd.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody
        MsgFwd.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: tnx! It helped me.
Now I have a problem : I need to copy the attachment to a new MailItem.
I try to do: `Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments` and `myAttachments.Add Item.Attachments.Item(1)` but it don't work

Comment: Can you post new question with your current code, @AndreyBaranov I’m here to help

Answer (score 0):

The message body may refer to hidden attachments used for `img` tags. So, if you copy the markup returned by the `HTMLBody` property you must also find and re-attach images used in the body. Except that, your code looks good:

```
Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MessageInfo
Dim Result
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    MsgBox ("debug msg")

    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("mail@mail.com")
    myItem.Subject = Item.Subject
    myItem.SendUsingAccount = oNS.Accounts.Item(2)
    myItem.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody
    myItem.Display
    'myItem.Send

End If
ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub
```

As a workaround, you may use the [Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply(method)) or [Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(method)) methods of the `MailItem` class. Both of them return a `MailItem` object that represents the new mail item. So, there is no need to copy anything. You just need recipients, correct the subject and call the `Send` method. For example:

```
Sub Forwarding()  
 Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector  
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
 Dim myattachments As Outlook.Attachments  

 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector  
 If Not TypeName(myinspector) = "Nothing" Then  
 Set myItem = myinspector.CurrentItem.Forward  

 ' myItem.Display  
 myItem.Recipients.Add "Eugene Astafiev"  
 myItem.Send 

 Else  
 MsgBox "There is no active inspector."  
 End If  
End Sub
```